# Can't access windows share

Tags: 14.04, samba, shared-folders, sharing

My sister has a Windows 7 laptop with some shared  folders over the network. From my Ubuntu  14.04 laptop in Files, Browse Network, I can see and access her workgroup but when I try to access her pc it keeps asking for credentials (user,workgroup,password). So it keeps asking over and over even know I already provide the right ones.

Comment: Have you accidentally done the username with any CaPiTalS? It should be all lowercase.

Comment: No, they are all lowercase

Comment: Has she set it to not allow the username you are using?

Comment: No, she shared the folder with everyone on the network not with a specific user only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this out.

1. Open Home folder(or any other folder, whatever)
2. Goto File-> Connect to Server
3. type your sister's IP with smb protocol e.g. smb://192.168.1.123/
4. Click Connect -> Enter Credentials.

   Please reply if you still get it repeatedly.

Comment: Working, thanks! but how come it did not work the other way around?

Comment: No idea ...  discovered by accident :-P

Comment: This is not working for me. Any suggestions?

Comment: On what version of Ubuntu? Any error message ? Pls describe