# Cannot see or access another computers on networking using ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, samba

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I am totally new to Ubuntu.
I have another computer with Windows 7 installed.
Both computers are connected via router using wifi.
But still I cannot see or access another system in Browse Network. What can be the issue here?
I tried alot of things : 
e.g modify and updating samba with following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install samba
$ gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

I tried changing:

From `browseable = no` to `browseable = yes`

Also tried:

```
$ gedit /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

**Changed:**

From

```
hosts: files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

To

```
hosts: files wins dns
```

Nothing works at all. Can anyone guide me whats wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just access the files from other **Windows** PCs, you can use [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/489337/cant-access-windows-share/489344#489344)

And
For other **Linux** PCs, you can install **ssh** server on them and access them by

```
$ssh username@ip-address
```

For remote desktop connection, [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/) is a nice cross-platform approach.