# How to access Windows shared folders/drives?

Tags: networking, windows, shared-folders

Whenever I am trying to browse Windows network from my Ubuntu machine, it takes some time to respond and shows an error message "UNABLE TO CONNECT WINDOWS NETWORK". I simply want to know, what are the basic steps to connect with a Windows machine from my Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: do you mean "lucid" as in the ubuntu release or as in "expressed clearly; easy to understand."?

Comment: I just simply need a clear and uncomplicated demonstration over the issue

Comment: you might find this useful: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't access windows share](http://askubuntu.com/questions/489337/cant-access-windows-share)